# Can somebody please explain how Vaadin security works with Spring?

Tags: spring-boot, security, vaadin, disable

The [Spring Security example](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/flow/integrations/spring/view-based-access-control) works and is clear. Vaadin has greatly improved integration with Spring security framework.

On the other side but it is not clear how the example can be modified. I made many attempts but got conflicts and errors.

I read there is no obligation to use the Vaadin Form, very well I would like to use my form, bare HTML generated with a servlet, let's say "my-login-form" endpoint. How can I actually insert it in the shown code so that Spring uses it as a login form and at the same Vaadin manages routes authorization?

Also, I would like to bypass or disable login during a test (without removing the spring-security dependency) and have all routes accessible. How can I do that?

Can anybody kindly provide an example?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: For the my-login-form you would need to exclude it from authentication. And what you mean by testing? TestBench? Unittests?

Comment: The problem was that I did not remove the setLoginView from `configure(Http)`; I shall use a custom form despite all work and overhead (template engine, HTML, CSS...)  because Vaadin form is limited (no success handler, no remember-me button...)

Comment: You can create a login view with Vaadin too